# run python code in c++

Tags: c++, python-2.7

I was making an app that needs to run python code in c++. But when I run this code it gives an segmentation fault in Linux. Does somebody have a clue what it could be?

```
  Py_SetProgramName("programName");
    Py_SetPythonHome("/usr/lib/python2.7");

    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");

    Py_Finalize();
```

Comment: Can you post the entire source code you are working with? (includes, etc.)

Comment: #include <Python.h>
I just include this. For this code

Comment: As far I know it will run until the py_initialize() then it will crash with a segementation fault

Comment: Sorry it will crash on the simpleString method

Comment: What os are you using? And what is in the Python file you are trying to execute?

Comment: Does its needs to be an pythonfile or can it just be pythin code

Comment: It can just be code, but in that case get rid of the "Py_SetProgramName" line. Also try it without the "Py_SetPythonHome" line and see if that is helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Use as follows:

```
#include <Python.h> // Attention: this MUST always be the first file included

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  // optional but recommended
    Py_Initialize();
    PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv);  
    // ...
```

Comment: what should be de params at PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv).?

Comment: They are the argc and argv arguments given by commandline to the cpp program. They must be forwarded to the Python code as well.  `argv[0]` is the program name. However, you don't have to specify anything special there.

Comment: would it so mutch difference with the PySys_setArgv(argc, argv); ?

Comment: Try and check by yourself... This is the recommended way, and it worked on my Linux system. Unfortunately, I haven't had a look at the internal implementation of these functions, so I cannot answer this question.

Comment: Ok i tried it but it gave a segmentation error. ok what else you need to know i use the naoqi sdk to compile it. here i make a module for my nao robot. this module needs to run the python code as you see above what you said. But when i run it i cant give params with it. Then i need to hard code the param what should i enter in the params?